# Can I use std::map::iterator as a base for a class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, iterator, incomplete-type

I need bijective mapping of values of two different types. I use `std::map`s for that. Part of real code:

```
struct endpoint
{
    site l, r;
    pedge e;
};

struct endpoint_less
{
     // comparator definition for `endpoint`
};

struct pevent; // forward declaration
using endpoints = std::map< endpoint, pevent, endpoint_less >;
using pendpoint = typename endpoints::iterator;

struct vertex { value_type x, y, R; };

struct event_less
{
    // comparator definition for `vertex`
};

using events = std::map< vertex, std::deque< pendpoint >, event_less >;
struct pevent { typename events::iterator ev; }; // currently I use composition
struct pevent : typename events::iterator {}; // but I want to use inheritance - it is much more convenient!
```

Looking at [n4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510) I don't see `std::map`, but in example above it seems, that practically (at least in the current *libc++*) member typedef (or type alias) `std::map::iterator` does not depend on `mapped_type`'s (and therefore on `value_type`'s) completeness.

In spite of Stadnard (in)conformance of using incomplete type as `mapped_type` can I be sure, that `std::map::iterator` is always a *class* (to use it as a base class)?

Can `std::map::iterator` be implemented, say, as a pointer, not a class? Say, not debug versions of iterators for `std::vector` often are pointers.

Comment: What is wrong??? Unclear what am I asking? There are `?` marks to visually distinct a question sentences from declarative sentences.

Comment: I sure the question is as clear as possible and have a value. Because it is idiomatic using of `std::map`s (bijective mapping - it is valuable application, which often arised in practice).

Comment: if `std::map::iterator` depends on `mapped_type` or not is, actually, a library implementation question. Most of compilers vendors implement "SCARY iterators" and remove that dependency. But it is not mandatory to implement it in that way. It is permitted but not required by the C++11 standard.

Comment: For the `vector` class is clear, since its requirements, that it could be implemented as a raw pointer. But for `map`, I don't see how to implement its iterator without using classes (or structs). For instance, `operator++` is not  just adding a fixed value to a pointer.

Comment: @Gonmator It possible to imagine such a hardware, which have memory specifically organized for trees. Pointers on such processor can behave as needed.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a real problem, or an imaginary one?

Comment: @Gonmator I solved [this](https://github.com/tomilov/sweepline/blob/develop/sweepline.hpp) problem. My choise is composition at the end.